# C how to use strcat with static offset char array

Tags: c, static, arrays, strcat

My current code looks like this (looks good on the eye but doesn't compile).

```
char FileConfPath[256];
char *pos;

GetModuleFileNameA(0, FileConfPath, 256);
pos= strrchr(FileConfPath, '\\');
if ( pos )
  strcat(FileConfPath[1], "file.conf");
else
  strcat(FileConfPath, "file.conf");
```

Generates 2 compiler errors.

```
error #2140: Type error in argument 1 to 'strcat'; expected 'char * restrict' but found 'char'.
```

Must I do

```
strcat(&FileConfPath[1], "file.conf");
```

doesn't look right to use addresses here.

Seems the error is for `FileConfPath[1]` only not for the one without the index specifier.

Comment: May not look right but is right. But what you're trying to achieve isn't exactly clear. Why would you copy to `FileConfPath[1]` just because a slash occurs _somewhere_ in the string?

Comment: I didn't write the code I decompiled it with Hex-Ray's just trying to make sense of it.. seems like some kind of detection thing for File Path's which `GetModuleFileName` may return either a folder path or a path with the slash missing? I don't know but either way I guess the slash is important to load the file later with `fopen`

Comment: Well, decompiling code has its risks and that code is almost certainly wrong. `strchr` will detect a slash **anywhere** in the path. So if the path contains `foo\bar` your code will fail because it will turn `foo\bar` into `ffile.conf`.

Comment: from reading the documentation seems `strrchr` detects only the last slash. `Locate last occurrence of character in string`

Comment: Yes, I overlooked that it was `strrchr` rather than `strchr`, but it will still fail in the same way.

Comment: Yeah probably shouldn't be `FileConfPath[1]` but maybe something with `pos+1` like the answer right? I can't really test it there is over 100 errors only will find out after a while if it's right or not. I'll accept the `&path[pos+1]` answer for now I guess that's what I need.

Comment: If what you're trying to do (and you didn't say) is append the file name after the last slash, then yes, the last paragraph of the accepted answer is correct.

Comment: That's most likely what it does yup, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way of placing `"file.conf"` after the initial character:

```
strcat(&FileConfPath[1], "file.conf");
```

`FileConfPath[1]` is the character at index one; `&FileConfPath[1]` is the address of the character at index one, which is what you want to pass to `strcat`.

Note that if you want to place `"file.conf"` after the slash, you want to use the address of the character after the slash, i.e.

```
strcpy(pos+1, "file.conf");
```

It goes without saying that `pos+11` (one for the slash plus one for null terminator plus nine for the characters of `"file.conf"`) needs to be less than or equal to `&FileConfPath[255]` to avoid buffer overrun.

Comment: First char? I think not.

Comment: @CareyGregory Maybe you're right - I edited the answer.

Comment: `[1]` means second haha `[0]` means first, but yeah figured I need to use `&` everytime I use index to char array. I find it strange without any index-specifier it's automatically a address? yet with it, I guess it's just a value?

Comment: If you use `pos` to put "file.conf" after the backslash, as shown in this answer, `pos + 1 + strlen("file.conf") + 1` better be < 256, or else you will have a buffer overflow.